# Close an inflated window layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a fragment activity that appears as a dialog window. I call to this activity this way:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Inflates the main layout to be used by this fragment*/
    final View detailView =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_detail_fragment, container, false);
```

In other part of the code, when I push a button of this layout, I need this activity to be closed, because it remains opened.

So, what will the way to finish this?

Comment: Layout cannot be started or finished, Activity or Fragment can.

Comment: Sorry about my english, that's what I wanted to say

Comment: You wrote that you're using Fragment Activity as your dialog but from the code you posted it seems that is Fragment... So what is it?